# How to communicate with microcontroller through a web interface?

Tags: microcontroller

Just a few days after we decided to travel, I thought I has to monitor the house somehow while we are away. So, I need to connect a microcontroller to the appliances and control it through web interface to turn them on or off, and what I'm trying to do is turning my home PC into a server and I've already installed apache and configured it, now to control the microcontroller through the webpage I need to send serial data over the DB9 port. The question is, what is the best way to send serial data from HTML? Is it through javascript or is it something else? And how?

Comment: too many good solutions to give one answer.  this is too broad and also primarily opinion based...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

HTML

Javascript

...and 1 language that has support for TCP sockets and devices (for DB9).

This could be c, c++, python, ruby, c#, Objective-C, Java and so on.

**Long Answer:**
**This system would have 3 components:**

1. The Web Server (HTML/Javascript/CSS)
2. The RESTful Server (C or Java or Other)
3. The DB9 Serial Server (Tiny C/Assembly/Other)

The best way to achieve those results is by creating what is called a RESTful API server written in a language that is well integrated into your operating system. You will have to write a program that accepts TCP connections, preferable over port 80 or 443 (for security). The program will then parse http data, headers and body etc, and issue a command to the micro controller accordingly.

Here is a good guide on Rest:
[Dr. Dobbs Rest](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069)

I'm assuming you know how to send data over a serial line. If your in linux and you have one mounted in the "dev" directory you can just write to the appropriate file. In other situations I've scripted the linux program "screen" before.

You can write your server program in any language that has access to TCP Sockets, which are normally facilitated by sys calls on your operating system.

The RESTful API can be separate from your actual HTML server program...which is apache. Then inside your delivered html content, include a javascript onclick event that will sent a restful request to your restful server.